# Region put in which not has been pushed

Tags: gemfire

I have the following Gemfire region:
    Region region;

After region.put(taskName, task) how can I determine in which node(GemFire peer) "task" has been pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach a listener to the region you will receive a create or update (or destroy) event on the member.

Have a look at this section of the documentation for details: http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/events/event_handler_overview.html

There are two types of listeners, `CacheListener`s and `AsyncEventListener`s. As the names may indicate, the former is synchronous and the latter is asynchronous.